# Haskell, combining Do and if

Tags: haskell

Hi I was wondering whether there was a way to use `do` `if` in haskell in this kind of way

```
doIfFunction :: Eq a => [a]->[a] ->[a]
doIfFunction l1 l2 = do
     if l /= something then (l2++something) else l2
     if l /= something2 then (l2++something2) else l2
     l2
```

Basically if this something function returns a different value I want it to add it to `l2` then return `l2`. I keep getting `l2` as being empty at the end and it shouldn't be, is this because of the `else l2` does it reset the value of `l2` to what it was at the start?

If so could I do something like this?

```
doIfFunction :: Eq a => [a]->[a] ->[a]
doIfFunction l1 l2 = do
     if l /= something then (let l2 = l2++something) else l2
     if l /= something2 then (let l2 = l2++something2) else l2
     l2
```

This gives errors, but I was wondering if this is on the right lines.

When the `doIfFunction` is being called it will always be `doIfFunction l []` where `l` contains values and `[]` is `empty`

Comment: Note that your (first) code only compiles because `[]` is a monad. If you tried to do the same thing with `l2` being, say, an `Int`, it would complain about a missing `Monad` instance. Because of the way the list monad is defined, your first code is equivalent to `concatMap (\_ -> concatMap (\_ -> l2) (if l /= something2 then (l2++something2) else l2)) (if l /= something then (l2++something) else l2)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just put the `if` clause in the `let` statement:

```
doIfFunction :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
doIfFunction l1 l2 = do
    let l2'  = if l /= something  then l2  ++ something  else l2
    let l2'' = if l /= something2 then l2' ++ something2 else l2'
    l2''
```

But in this case you don't really need the `do` notation since you don't use any monadic operation. I believe you want to use the `do` notation to simulate imperative-style programming. Consider using a `where` if you think it's more readable:

```
doIfFunction :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
doIfFunction l1 l2 = result
    where newL2 = if l /= something  then l2 ++ something  else l2
        result = if l /= something2 then newL2 ++ something2 else newL2
```

Alternatively, when you will be more familiar with Haskell, you could use [leftaroundabout's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34254954/5559663) (that would be the most idiomatic way to write what you want to do).

Answer (score 4):

Generally, you should avoid to think about *modifying* anything in Haskell. In fact, you can't, the language doesn't allow it. At all<sup>†</sup>!

Instead of modifying the list `l2` itself, you think about creating additional lists which are *modified versions* of `l2`. (The immediate benefit is that you can still use the original `l2` anywhere else; in particular it's fine if some other function / thread still needs this old version and you weren't aware of it.)

I.e., instead of

```
 do
   modify_something_about_l2
   modify_something_else_about_l2
   yield_some_result
```

you want to just *evaluate the result* of a function-application chain, like

```
f l2 = some_other_modification (some_modification (l2))
```

or, as we prefer to write it,

```
f = some_other_modification . some_modification
```

In your particular case:

```
doIfFunction l1
  = (\l2 -> if l /= something2 then (l2++something2) else l2)
    . (\l2 -> if l /= something then (l2++something) else l2)
```

If you don't like the “backwards style“ you can also replace the composition operator `.` with its flipped version:

```
import Control.Arrow

doIfFunction l1
  = (\l2 -> if l /= something then (l2++something) else l2)
   >>> (\l2 -> if l /= something2 then (l2++something2) else l2)
```

Also, you can, via eta-reduction, avoid mentioning the intermediate lists at all:

```
doIfFunction l1
  = (if l /= something then (++something) else id)
   >>> (if l /= something2 then (++something2) else id)
```

---

### That said...

You're probably thinking: it's mighty inefficient to always create *new modified versions* of everything, instead of just modifying in-place. Well, sometimes it is, often it is actually no problem at all.

You example is in fact one where it is a problem: to append `something` to `l2`, a copy of the entire list needs to be made. Maybe you can avoid this problem very easily: if instead of *appending*, you *prepend*:

```
doIfFunction l1
  = (if l /= something then (something++) else id)
   >>> (if l /= something2 then (something2++) else id)
```

then there's no performance penalty. The reason being: a list is just a chain of elements (heads), each with references to the rest of the list. *Pre*-pending an element is just a matter of making a new head and linking it to the already existing list!

---

<sup>†</sup><sub>Even with clever lazy prepending, sometimes the pure-functional style *is* significantly more time-expensive. Don't worry: although Haskell does not allow modifying values, there are types which *encapsulate the concept of destructive modifications*, namely the [`ST` monad](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Control-Monad-ST-Lazy-Safe.html#t:ST). So you can still implement algorithms that need destructive updates efficiently, but basically you don't do it in Haskell but in an embedded “domain-specific imperative language”, that integrates seamlessly with Haskell.</sub>

Comment: @dfeuer: mainly to avoid scope confusion with three different `l2` variables. Also because – not always but often – point-free definitions are simply cleaner. I agree that pointless may be confusing to a beginner, but I hope I have made sufficiently accessible steps in my explanation.